# Play local GIF using AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, gif

We are trying to play local GIF using AVPlayer. Does AVPlayer supports GIF format? This is what we tried:

```
   guard let gifUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myGif", withExtension: "gif") else {
        return
    }

    let gifPlayer = AVPlayer(url: gifUrl)
    self.videoContainer.player = gifPlayer
    self.videoContainer.player?.play()
```

**Is it possible to play GIF with AVPlayer?**

**Any help or advice will be highly appreciated. Thank you.**

**Best Regards, Roi**

Comment: https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage

Comment: This is not supported. You can use LFAnimatedImage or similar library or if you still wish to use AVPlayer convert the .gif to video.mp4 and loop it.

Answer (score -4):

You can try these steps to play local video using AVPlayer in swift:-

1) First of all add the video into your xcode project.

2) Check your added video in Bundle. Select your project your Target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources.

If video is not available in Copy Bundle Resources then you can add by tapping on Plus button.

3) Use the following code in you project.

import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    playVideo()
}

private func playVideo() {
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video", ofType:"m4v") else {
        debugPrint("video.m4v not found")
        return
    }
    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController.player = player
    present(playerController, animated: true) {
        player.play()
    }
}
```

}

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer the question: "Can AVPlayer play GIFs".. to which the answer is no.

Comment: Hey Swati. Thank you for replying. As @Brandon said I need to play GIF and not a video.

Comment: Hi Roi. You can get the help from this link to play GIF. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQRPBs4qVJA. Following is the link which provide the code to run GIF in swift:- https://github.com/swiftgif/SwiftGif/blob/master/SwiftGifCommon/UIImage%2BGif.swift